# ¿Como solucionar los espacios entre los elementos inline-block?

Tags: html, css, css3

Cuando uso elementos con la propiedad `inline-block` me aparece un espacio entre los elementos:

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.padre .hijo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 1</div>
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 2</div>
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 3</div>
</div>
```

¿Por que pasa esto y hay alguna manera de eliminar este efecto?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El comportamiento de los espacios es parte de los elementos `inline` y `inline-block`.

Por defecto a los elementos `inline` se les aplican las propiedades `letter-spacing` y `word-spacing` ([Ver índice de propiedad](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#property-index)) las cuales dependen del tamaño `font-size` que heredan del elemento padre y al estar los elementos en cada linea por separado, se genera al renderizar el `DOM` un espacio blanco (visualizado con un `_`:

```
<div class="hijo">Hijo 1</div>_
<div class="hijo">Hijo 2</div>_
<div class="hijo">Hijo 3</div>_
```

Vamos a ver ahora multitudes soluciones que le puedes dar al problema para eliminar los espacios en el `DOM` o con reglas en el `CSS`:

**#1. Quitar los espacios entre los elementos:**

- **Pro**: No se necesita ninguna regla adicional en el `CSS`
- **Contra**: No es legible y difícil de mantener el código

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.padre .hijo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Ejemplo #1 -->

<div class="padre">
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 1</div><div class="hijo">Hijo 2</div><div class="hijo">Hijo 3</div>
</div>

<br><!-- Ejemplo #2 -->

<div class="padre">
  <div class="hijo">
  Hijo 1
  </div><div class="hijo">
  Hijo 2
  </div><div class="hijo">
  Hijo 3
  </div>
</div>

<br><!-- Ejemplo #3 (trasladamos el '>' del cierre a la próxima linea -->

<div class="padre">
  <div class="hijo">
  Hijo 1
  </div
  ><div class="hijo">
  Hijo 2
  </div
  ><div class="hijo">
  Hijo 3
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**#2. Añadir comentarios (vacíos):**

- **Pro**: No se necesita ninguna regla adicional en el `CSS`
- **Contra**: Puede ser molesto al escribir/leer

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.padre .hijo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
     <div class="hijo">Hijo 1</div><!--
  --><div class="hijo">Hijo 2</div><!--
  --><div class="hijo">Hijo 3</div>
</div>
```

---

**#3. Establecemos el tamaño de fuente `font-size` a cero**

- **Pro**: No se necesita ninguna modificación en el `DOM`
- **Contra**: Hay que añadir nuevas reglas al `CSS`

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.padre {
  font-size: 0; /* Reducimos */
}

.padre .hijo {

  font-size: 1rem; /* Restablecemos */
 
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 1</div>
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 2</div>
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 3</div>
</div>
```

---

**#4. Arreglo `white-space` con `margin`**

- **Pro**: No se necesita ninguna modificación en el `DOM`
- **Contra**: Hay que añadir nuevas reglas al `CSS`

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.padre .hijo {

  margin-right: -4px;
 
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 1</div>
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 2</div>
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 3</div>
</div>
```

---

**#5. Restamos en `letter-spacing`**

- **Pro**: No se necesita ninguna modificación en el `DOM`
- **Contra**: Hay que añadir nuevas reglas al `CSS`

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.padre {
   letter-spacing: -1em; /* Restamos */
}

.padre .hijo { 

  letter-spacing: normal; /* Vuelta a lo normal */ 
  
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 1</div>
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 2</div>
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 3</div>
</div>
```

---

**#6. `flex` in the house (gracias a los navegadores modernos)**

- **Pro**: No se necesita ninguna modificación en el `DOM`
- **Contra**: Hay que añadir nuevas reglas al `CSS`

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.padre {
   display: flex;
}

.padre .hijo { 
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 1</div>
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 2</div>
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 3</div>
</div>
```

---

Fuentes:

- [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3)
- [SO - How to remove the space between inline-block elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)
- [EsCSS - Display: inline-block y sus espacios de separación](https://escss.blogspot.com.es/2012/03/display-inline-block-y-sus-empeno-en.html)
- [css-tricks - Fighting the space between inline-block elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: Entonces, entre todas las opciones cual es la mejor ?

Comment: @CamiloVasquez - Esto es ya depende de cada uno y/o situación del código (personalmente yo prefiero las manipulaciones por `CSS`)

Answer (score 2):

Puede reemplazar `display: inline-block` por `float:left` así:

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.padre .hijo {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 1</div>
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 2</div>
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 3</div>
</div>
```