# CSS - Div con imagen no queda dentro de Div Padre

Tags: css, html5

Tengo un problema, tengo 3 `div` con un `img` y un párrafo con la descripción de la imagen, estos 3 `div` los tengo dentro de un `div` Padre.

El problema es que mis 3 `div` quedan por fuera de mi `div` padre, osea, queda mitad en `div` padre y mitad por fuera, me di cuenta de eso porque le di un `background` color al `div` padre.

```css
/*MOSTRAR IMAGEN*/

#contenedor_busqueda {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px;
    background-color: darkgoldenrod;
}

#imgIzq {
    float: left;
}

#imgMed {
    float: left;
}

#imgDer {
    float: left;
}


/*FIN MOSTRAR IMAGEN*/
```

```html
<!-- imagenes del resultado de busqueda -->
<div id="contenedor_busqueda">
    <div id="imgIzq">
        <img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="3" width="200" height="200">
        <p>Fab/Art/Desc/Color</p>
    </div>
    <div id="imgMed">
        <img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="3" width="200" height="200">
        <p>Fab/Art/Desc/Color</p>
    </div>
    <div id="imgDer">
        <img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="3" width="200" height="200">
        <p>Fab/Art/Desc/Color</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como podría hacer para que me quede correcto? los 3 `div` dentro del `div` padre! Es por la imagen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cuando utilizas la propiedad `float: left` los elementos que tienen dicha propiedad flotaran uno después de otro lo que "rompe" por decirlo así la estructura del DOM y es por esto que pareciera que se salen de su contenedor padre aunque realmente no es así, lo que pasa es que el contenedor padre no es capaz de recobrar la altura automática en base a su contenido.

En tu ejemplo vez el `background` del contenedor padre debido a que estás aplicando la propiedad `padding` y le estas dando un valor de `100px` en todos los lados, entonces la altura que vez del `div` padre es simplemente el `padding-top` y el `padding-bottom`.

Existen muchas formas de solucionar esto, una de ellas es usar las propiedades `display: inline-block` y `vertical-align: center`.

Como se explica en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/123051/como-solucionar-los-espacios-entre-los-elementos-inline-block/123052#123052):

> Por defecto a los elementos inline se les aplican las propiedades letter-spacing y word-spacing las cuales dependen del tamaño font-size que heredan del elemento padre y al estar los elementos en cada linea por separado, se genera al renderizar el DOM un espacio blanco.

Es por esto que he agregado al codigo **CSS** la propiedad `letter-spacing` al `div` padre con un valor de `-1em` y a los `div` hijos con un valor `normal`

```css
/*MOSTRAR IMAGEN*/

#contenedor_busqueda {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px;
    background-color: darkgoldenrod;
    letter-spacing: -1em;
}

#imgIzq {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: center;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

#imgMed {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: center;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

#imgDer {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: center;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}


/*FIN MOSTRAR IMAGEN*/
```

```html
<!-- imagenes del resultado de busqueda -->
<div id="contenedor_busqueda">
    <div id="imgIzq">
        <img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="3" width="200" height="200">
        <p>Fab/Art/Desc/Color</p>
    </div>
    <div id="imgMed">
        <img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="3" width="200" height="200">
        <p>Fab/Art/Desc/Color</p>
    </div>
    <div id="imgDer">
        <img src="img/zapato.jpg" border="3" width="200" height="200">
        <p>Fab/Art/Desc/Color</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias he podido resolver mi problema! En que momentos seria correcto usar float: left?

Comment: @tato8vio depende de cada quien el usarlo o no, yo personalmente NUNCA lo uso por varias implicaciones que tiene por ejm tendría que usar la propiedad `clear: both` para los elementos siguientes que no quiero que floten... yo uso mucho la propiedad que te explico en la respuesta y el `display: flex`